# bootstrap-generators not using the templates when building a new scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a brand new rails app and want to use the [bootstrap-generators](https://github.com/decioferreira/bootstrap-generators) gem.
I have followed the instructions on their website, but if I now generate a scaffold **I don't get the bootstrap styled inputs/buttons/etc**.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBP2U.png)

Notice that the button is the standard rails button, not the nice bootstrap button. As you can see, the main layout does have bootstrap theme working

I can see that the bootstrap template files are in the /lib/templates/erb/scaffold folder. If I now create a new scaffold it seems that these templates are ignored.

What am I missing, and why woudn't the bootstrap scaffold templates be used?

Comment: Please add the html, the routes.rb and the controller to your question.

Comment: Nothing has changed from the default rails app, and the one scaffold was built using: rails generate scaffold Cat

Comment: I got the same problem, do you have already a solution?

Comment: It was actually because spring was running in the background. I had to kill spring and it all started working after that. I'm very surprised this is not mentioned on the bootstrap-generators page.

Answer (score 2):

Spring was running in the background and therefore the new template files were not being loaded. Simply typing 'spring stop' fixed all my problems :)

Comment: To clarify: you need to run the 'spring stop' command before running the rails scaffold command. Running the scaffold command with the --force option should fix all of the problems caused by spring without any prompts.